# Directory Picker (Chooser) using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to make a web app using laravel that enables thie user to choose a directory where the application results will be saved

I am trying to use api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showDirectoryPicker

```
async function getDir() {
   const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
   // run code for dirHandle
}
```

but I don't know how to get the full path after getting the directory handle

Comment: Why would you need a full path?

Comment: I don't think, it is meant to be possible for security reasons

Comment: I want the user to choose save location, so I need the full path